# FPU extension '+fpv5' and '+fp.dp' has no effect to the output binary (STM32F767ZIT ARM Cortex-M7)

Tags: c, arm, stm32, fpu

I want to apologize in advance if there are any errors in the text, because I'm not very well in English yet :)

I'm using VSCode on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.1) to build and debug projects for STM32. When I started to work with STM32F767ZIT, I found that it has hardware unit to accelerate operations with floating point numbers.

*Datasheet: "The Cortex®-M7 core features a floating point unit (FPU) which supports Arm double-precision and single-precision data-processing instructions and data types").*

I'm using Arm Embedded Toolchain ((15:9-2019-q4-0ubuntu1) 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599]) to build the sources and create *.elf file. When I compiling the objects, I'm using next command:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc "foo.c" -c -march=armv7e-m+fp.dp -mtune=cortex-m7 -g3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -o "foo.o"
```

And when linking all objects:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -march=armv7e-m+fp.dp -mtune=cortex-m7 -g3 -mthumb -T"flash.ld" -o "target.elf" "objects.o"
```

As you can see, I use "+fp.dp" extension, that enabling the single- and double-precision FPv5 floating-point instructions. My main function is only for testing, and looks like:

```
int main()
{
    double var = 1.1;
    var *= 1.2;
    var += 1.3;
    if (var > 1.4) {
        var /= 1.5;
        var -= 1.6;
    }
}
```

So when I've build the project I have the next result:
`text:3412 data:1084 bss:1568 dec:6064 hex:17b0`

But, when I disable FPU extension and using *-march=armv7e-m+nofp*, I have the same sizes of the output binary. I thought that when I disabling FPU extension the compiler should use additional library to handle floating point numbers operations, so the size of my binary file should be greater. Also, I've test the productivity, and it's the same to both cases.

Also, I've try to use additional parameters:

```
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-d16
```

In that case the size of binary file is much less, than in previous two examples, and also I've look in the disassembled files, and found commands like: *vldr*, *vmul*, etc. But this code doesn't work, when I'm try to execute any of the FPU assembly command the program jump to the *HardFault_Handler*.

So my questions is:

1. Why extension "+fp.dp" and "+nofp" has no effect to the output binary?
2. Why my code is crashed when trying to execute any of FPU commands?

I'll be glad of any yours ideas, questions and *maybe even* solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why my code is crashed when trying to execute any of FPU commands?

Because you need to enable the FPU first. Otherwise, it will generate the HF as there is nothing to interpret the FPU instructions.

```
SCB->CPACR |= ((3UL << (10*2))|(3UL << (11*2)));
```

> Why extension "+fp.dp" and "+nofp" has no effect to the output binary?

Because you did not tell the compiler to generate the FPU instructions. Remeber that you will have to link against the ABI HARD FPU libraries as well.

USE OPTIONS: `-mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-d16`

forget about  "+fp.dp" etc etc.

Comment: Thank you! It really was because I didn't enabled FPU first.
BTW I also found that CMSIS enable FPU in function SystemInit, but I tested without it.

Comment: SystemInit is a part of HAL not CMSIS

Comment: I mean that I found this function in the "STM32CubeF7-master/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F7xx/Source/Templates/system_stm32f7xx.c" file. It's a part of the Cube packet, but placed in the CMSIS driver folder :)